# Why won't my program work?

Tags: java, performance, poker

I have a java program that I had working perfectly, but somehow, overtime it failed. I'm really not sure how and I'm not sure why, so I'm hoping a new pair of eyes will help solve the problem. Please help, thanks! The program is a simple "poker" code that outputs 5 random cards from the deck.

The program was working when I first ran it but for some strange reason it doesn't run anymore.

```
I keep getting the errors...
"cannot resolve symbol rank.length",
"cannot resolve symbol suit.length",
"Package java.Random does not exist"
```

The Program:

```
import java.Random.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Poker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //initialize variables
        int suits = suit.length;
        int ranks = rank.length;
        int n = suits * ranks;
        //counter
        int m = 5;

         // create a deck of 52 cards
         String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
         String[] rank = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                           "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
                         };


         // initialize deck
         String[] deck = new String[n];
         for (int i = 0; i < ranks; i++) { 
             for (int j = 0; j < suits; j++) { 
                 deck[suits*i + j] = rank[i] + " of " + suit[j]; 

         }
         }

        // create random 5 cards
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)  {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i));
            String t = deck[r];
            deck[r] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = t;
        }

        // print results
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            System.out.println(deck[i]);

        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you are getting?

Comment: "Overtime it failed".. What failed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cannot resolve symbol rank.length

That's because you try to access `rank.length` before declaring `rank`.

Try:

```
//first declare arrays
// create a deck of 52 cards
String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
String[] rank = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                   "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
                 };

//then find out their length
int suits = suit.length;
int ranks = rank.length;
int n = suits * ranks;
//counter
int m = 5;
```

---

> Package java.Random does not exist

It's true, it's `import java.util.Random`, not `import java.Random.*`, the `java.Random` package doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

First, the package `java.Random` really does not exist.  But I don't see where you're using `Random` anyway, so just remove that import statement.  Even if you were using `Random`, you are already importing it with `java.util.*`.

For the other two errors, you declared the variables you're referring to (`suit` and `rank`) after you used them.  Declare them before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int suits = suit.length;
  int ranks = rank.length;
  int n = suits * ranks;

the above lines should be placed below

String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
String[] rank = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                           "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
                };

also remove import java.Random.*
```